# Laravel Mix 0.10.0 - Version only specific files

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, webpack, laravel-mix

How is it possible to just version specific files and ignore others.

My webpack.mix.js file looks as following

```
const {mix} = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .extract(['axios', 'lodash']);

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/pdf.scss', 'public/css');

mix.version();
```

I tried to attach version only to the mix.js and the first mix.sass but I renders all the files.

I would like to exclude versioning for the pdf.scss file. As I've read a comment on GitHub from Jeffrey Way, it seems that all files processed through mix.sass and mix.js are versionend when mix.version() is called. May I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know a way to exclude files from versioning, but you can actually specify which files should be versioned.

https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/472

You can specify an array in `mix.version()` to define which files should be versionend:

`mix.version(['path/to/file.css'])`